# Laravel router redirect to wrong path

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I wrote this code expecting to be redirected to the root url (`/` or `/home`), but instead, it's redirecting to `%7Bhome%7D`.

```
Route::get('/{home}', ['as' => 'home', function () {
   return view('home');
}])->where('home', '(home)?');
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

note: it does support both urls (`/` or `/home`). the problem is just when calling for its name on redirects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can You provide the code where You're doing redirect?

Comment: @num8er sure! it's a simple `return redirect()->route('home');`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is just to create two routes with the two URLs:

```
Route::get('/', 'yourController@methodName');
```

and the other one:

```
Route::get('/home', 'yourController@methodName');
```

As you might know, the %7B and %7D are referring to the left and right curly braces { }.  I'm not sure why, but it's obviously not leaving out the curly braces when it tries to direct to your route .

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but what if I'd extend the variety? if I support multiple languages, I'd have to create one for each idiom, which looks messy

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that You cannot redirect using named routes.
Give a try to this:

```
Route::get('{location}', ['as' => 'home', function ($location = 'home') {
   return view($location);
}])->where('location', '(home)?');
```

or how about this:

```
Route::any('/', ['as' => 'home', function () {
   return view('home');
}]);
```